# Как в функцию schedule вставить значение масива?

Tags: python, schedule

Я парсю два дива в которых находяться значение времени. див1(4:50) и див2(15:30) для примера. Потом оказываеться что когда наступает время второго дива.. его значение переходит в див1, а в див2 заходит другое время.

```
time_parse = soup.find_all('div', class_='time')
times = []
for item in time_parse:
    times += item
```

Я решил обмануть судьбу таким образом. Просто поменять местами ячейки. В итоге по сути будет то что мне нужно.

```
def change_for_time(changes_time):
    changes_time[0], changes_time[1] = changes_time[1], changes_time[0]
    return changes_time
print (change_for_time(times))
```

Теперь как мне выполнять это действие каждый день? Я решил попробывать использьвовать schedule. Но как мне вставить туда время 0й ячейки?

```
schedule.every().day.at(time[0]).do(change_for_time)
```

оно не захотело. Ему нужно так указывать...

```
schedule.every().day.at('10:30').do(change_for_time)
```

Comment: time[0] преобразуйте в нужный формат. Из кода не понятно что находится в time[0]

Comment: print(type(times[0])) пишет что <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Попробуем зайти с другой стороны. Добавьте в вопрос кусок HTML из переменной`time_parse`. `print(time_parse)`

Comment: [<div class="time">4:46</div>, <div class="time">20:57</div>]

Comment: Чтоб из `NavigableString` достать обычную строку, [нужно сделать](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) `times[0].unicode()`. Вопрос не относится ни к schedule ни к массивам...

Answer (score 0):

```
#[<div class="time">4:46</div>, <div class="time">20:57</div>]

times =[item.text for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='time')]

# ['4:46','20:57']
```

Рабочий пример

```
from time import sleep
import schedule

def job():
    print(time[0])

time = [":03"]
schedule.every().minute.at(time[0]).do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Теперь показывает <class 'str'> schedule.every().day.at(time[0]).do(change_for_time) 
не работает по прежнему.

Comment: Что имеено у вас не работает? Не запускается задача для планировщика? Или проблемы с логикой кода?

Comment: Мне нужно первый элемент масиива times[0] засудунь в schedule.every().day.at('10:30').do(change_for_time) вместо '10:30'...